# Return true if character immediately before and after the '*' in string are Same

Tags: java

I am a beginner in Java
I don't get why my if statement is wrong

```
public boolean sameStarChar(String str)
     {
         int len = str.length();

         for(int x = 1; x < length-1; x++)
           {
              if (str.charAt(x) == '*' && str.charAt(x-1) == str.charAt(x+1))
                return true;
           }
              else 
             return false;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Your method only checks the first star in the string, not every star.

Comment: your if statement is inside loop and else outside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing start your loop from `x=0` because the index of first element in 0.

```
str.charAt(x-1) == str.charAt(x+1)
```

this condition return true only if the previous and next character of `*` are same.

```
public boolean sameStarChar(String str)
 {
     int len = str.length();
     int no=0,yes=0; 
     for(int x = 0; x < len-1; x++)
       {
         if (str.charAt(x) == '*')
         {
            if((str.charAt(x-1)>='a' && str.charAt(x-1)<='z') && (str.charAt(x+1)>='a' && str.charAt(x+1)<='z'))
            {
              yes++;
            }  
            else{
              no++;
            }
         }
       }
    if(no>0)
        return false;
    else 
        return true;
```

}

What I have do is that I uses a flag variable `no` and `yes` and keep track of your condition.

Hopefully that helps.